# Alert Dialog not showing properly Android 13

Tags: java, android

> Hello dear developers! , I'm having an issue with an Alert Dialog not showing properly in Android 13 using Java for Android development. Has anyone else encountered this problem or have any insights on how to resolve it? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
    private void showOptionalUpdateDialog() {
        if (!isFinishing()) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Update Available")
                    .setMessage("A new version of the app is available. Do you want to update?")
                    .setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            redirectToAppStore();
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("Not Now", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            // Handle "Not Now" button click
                            Log.e("NotNow", "click");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    })
                    .setCancelable(false);

            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

          
        }
    }
```

> This is the Output screenshot :
> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output screen is showing "Update Available" and the buttons and content of the dialog is not clearly visible, it might be due to changes in the default styling of AlertDialogs in Android 13.
To ensure that buttons and content is displayed properly you can try applying a custom theme to the AlertDialog. By applying a custom theme, you can customize the appearance and style of the AlertDialog to ensure that it displays correctly in Android 13 and matches the overall look and feel of your app.